# Address Book Program Using Struct

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

I'm new to C++, taking my first course, and as one of the assignments we have to create a record management program.

One of the things it has to do is be able to sort the records and display them in a certain order.

I'm creating an address book program, and so far I can add the contacts, display them, save them to a file, and open the file. I'm now trying to sort the contacts by first name, alphabetically, but I'm running into problems. The main one is that the program has to use struct, and I'm trying to sort by a string in the struct, which I have never done before.

I'm also struggling with having to find and display a specific record for editing or removal, though I've made some progress on that.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it. I've been fighting with this for days.

Here is my current code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct AddressBook {
string firstname; 
string lastname;
string addr; 
string phone;
};

// Function prototypes
char getMenuResponse(); // Function to allow user to navigate program.
void addContacts(vector<AddressBook>&); // Function to add contacts.
void dispContacts(const vector<AddressBook>&); // Function to display contacts.
void saveFile(const vector<AddressBook>&); // Function to save to file.
void openFile(vector<AddressBook>&); // Function to read from file.
int findTargetFirstName(vector<AddressBook>& list, string target); // Function to find a target index
void findContact(vector<AddressBook>&); // Function to find a contact.

void sortFirstNames(vector<AddressBook>& list);

int main() {

// To operate, to avoid losing previous contacts, Open File first

vector<AddressBook> list;
bool run = true;

cout << "Welcome To My Address Book Program For Assignment 2!\n" << endl;

do {
    switch (getMenuResponse()) {
        case 'A': addContacts(list); break; 
        case 'D': dispContacts(list); break;
        case 'M': sortFirstNames(list); break;
        case 'O': openFile(list); break; 
        case 'S': saveFile(list); break; 
        case 'F': findContact(list); break;
        case 'Q': run = false; break;
        default : cout << "That is NOT a valid choice" << endl;
        }
    } while (run);

cout << endl << "Program Terminated" << endl;

// system("PAUSE"); // Commented out so the program exits upon request
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void sortFirstNames(vector<AddressBook>& list) {
string firstname;
int i, j, min;

bool sorted = false;
bool run = true;

if(list[i].firstname > 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < (list[i].firstname-1); i++) {
    min = i;
    for (j = (i+1); j < list[i].firstname; j++) {
        if(list[j] < list[min]) min = j;
    }
if (i != min) swap(list[i], list[min]);
}
sorted = true;
}       
}


int findTargetFirstName(vector<AddressBook>& list, string target) {
// linear search:
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
if (list[i].firstname == target) return i; // return ndx of target
return -1; // not in the list
}

void findContact(vector<AddressBook>& list) {
if(list.size() > 0) {
    string firstname;

    cout << "Enter the first name to find: ";
    getline(cin, firstname);
    int ndx = findTargetFirstName(list, firstname);

    if (ndx >= 0) {
        cout << firstname << " is at index " << ndx << "." << endl;
    } else cout << firstname << " is not found!" << endl;
} else cout << "That name is not found!" << endl;
}

void addContacts(vector<AddressBook>& list) {
AddressBook tmp; // Declare a temp contact that we will load before putting in the array.
char response;
string str; // Needed for cin.getline; we are going to use a char array.
bool run = true;

do {
    system("cls");
    cout << "Enter Contact Information" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 'quit' at Name to exit." << endl << endl;

    cout << "First Name: "; // Entering first name.
    getline(cin, str); 
    tmp.firstname = str;
    cout << endl;

    if (str == "quit") break;

    cout << "Last Name: "; // Entering last name.
    getline(cin, str); 
    tmp.lastname = str;
    cout << endl;       

    cout << "Address: "; // Entering Address
    getline(cin, str);
    tmp.addr = str;
    cout << endl;       

    cout << "Phone Number: "; // Entering phone number.
    getline(cin, str);
    tmp.phone = str;
    cout << endl;

    // See if this record should be added to the array.
    cout << "Add Contact to Address Book? (y/n) ";
    cin >> response;
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    if (toupper(response) == 'Y')  {
        list.push_back(tmp);
        cout << "Contact added!"<< endl;
    }else {
        cout << "Contact not added!" << endl;
    }

} while (run);
system("cls");
 }

 void dispContacts(const vector<AddressBook>& list) {

system("cls");

// If there is nothing in the list, statement that there are no contacts.
// Otherwise, continue.
if(list.size() < 1) {
    cout << "Nothing to display" << endl;
} else { 
    cout << "Contacts :" << endl << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2); 
    cout << "Contact Name Address Phone No." << endl;
    cout << "*******************************************" << endl;

    cout << left; 
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        cout << setw(15) << list[i].firstname << left
            << setw(15) << list[i].lastname << left
            << setw(30) << list[i].addr << left
            << setw(15) << list[i].phone << left << endl;
    }

cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
cout << right << setw(3) << list.size();
cout << " Contacts"<< endl;
}

system("PAUSE");
system("cls");
}

// Save records to file.
void saveFile(const vector<AddressBook>& list) {

string fileName;
ofstream outfi;
cout<<"Enter file name (please use addressbook.txt for now): ";
// Have set file name to addressbook.txt for now.
// Might change code to allow selection of file to load.
getline(cin,fileName);
outfi.open(fileName.c_str());

// To make sure the file stream is open before doing IO.
if (!outfi.fail()) { 
system("cls"); 
cout << "Saving Address Book to the disc ";

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    outfi << list[i].firstname << ';' 
    << list[i].lastname << ';'
    << list[i].addr << ';' 
    << list[i].phone;
    // Start a new line after all but the last record.
    // Simplifies reading the file as EOF is at end of last line.
    if (i < list.size()-1) outfi << endl;
}

cout << endl << list.size() << " Address Book written to the disc." << endl;
outfi.close();

system("PAUSE");
system("cls");
} else { // Something went wrong with writing to the file.
    cout << "ERROR: problem with file" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    system("cls");
}
}

// Open file and load array
void openFile(vector <AddressBook>& list) {

AddressBook tmp;

// If Open File is selected after contacts are added, they will be overwritten.
// Warning user that this will occur.
// If 'N' selected, Open File will not continue, and will return to GetMenuResponse.
if (list.size() > 0) {
    char response;
    cout << "Are you sure?  If you have already added contacts, this will " 
        << "overwrite what you have entered with a previously saved "
        << "addressbook.txt." << endl;
    cout << "Do you wish to proceed? (Y/N) : ";
    cin >> response;
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    if(toupper(response) == 'N') return;
}

ifstream infi("addressbook.txt"); // Have set file name to addressbook.txt for now.
// Might change code to allow selection of file to load.
string str;

// Make sure the file stream is open before doing IO.
if (!infi.fail()) { 

    system("cls");
    cout << "Reading Address Book from the disc ";

    list.clear(); // Overwrite any existing records

    getline(infi, str, ';');
    while(!infi.eof()) {
        // Store the first name.
        tmp.firstname = str;
        // Store the last name.
        getline(infi, str, ';');
        tmp.lastname = str;
        // Store the address.           
        getline(infi, str, ';');
        tmp.addr = str; 
        // Store the phone number.      
        getline(infi, str);
        tmp.phone = str;        
        // Put tmp into the vector.
        list.push_back(tmp);

        getline(infi, str, ';');
    }
    cout << endl << list.size() << " Contacts read from the disc." << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    system("cls");
} else { // Something went wrong with opening the file.
    cout << "ERROR: problem with file" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    system("cls");
}
}

// Get's user's input from keyboard.
char getMenuResponse() {
char response;
cout << endl << "Make your selection" << endl
    << "(A)dd contact, \n(D)isplay Contacts, \n(M)Sort By First Name, "
    << "\n(O)pen File, \n(S)ave File, "
    <<"\n(F)ind Index Of Contact By First Name, \n(Q)uit" << endl
    << "> ";
cin >> response;
cin.ignore(256, '\n'); 
// Clean-up up to 256 chars including the delimiter specified (\n, the endl) 
// OR stop when the \n is encountered after removing it.
return toupper(response);
}
```

I've tried two different ways for the sort so far.
The first gives me errors like:
69  25 [Error] no match for 'operator>' in '(& list)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] >(((std::vector::size_type)i)).AddressBook::firstname > 1'

```
void sortFirstNames(vector<AddressBook>& list) {
string firstname;
int i, j, min;

bool sorted = false;
bool run = true;

if(list[i].firstname > 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < (list[i].firstname-1); i++) {
    min = i;
    for (j = (i+1); j < list[i].firstname; j++) {
        if(list[j] < list[min]) min = j;
    }
if (i != min) swap(list[i], list[min]);
}
sorted = true;
}       
}
```

The second (and for this one I used #include ) gives me errors like:
66  23  [Error] 'class std::vector' has no member named 'firstname'

```
void sortFirstNames(vector<AddressBook>& list) {
string firstname;
char i;

for (i = 0; i < list.firstname; i++) {
    sort(list.begin(), list.end());
}
}
```

With help, I'm trying the std::sort function, but while the code compiles it doesn't actually display anything.

```
struct AddrCmpFirstNames {
bool operator ()(const AddressBook& lhs, const AddressBook& rhs) 
{
    return lhs.firstname < rhs.firstname;
}
};

void sortFirstNames(std::vector<AddressBook>& vec) {
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), AddrCmpFirstNames());
cout << endl;
}
```

I declared the vector in the main, and called the function, but it just displays a blank line.
I know I'm missing something very basic.

Comment: are you receiving any errors?

Comment: Is there a *specific* problem with code *you've written* that doesn't seem to behave as you intended?

Comment: I've tried two different sort functions so far.  The first was:

Comment: Attempts and their results should be in the *question* please. Don't paste walls of code as comments.

Comment: void sortFirstNames(vector<AddressBook>& list) {
 string firstname;
 int i, j, min;
 
 bool sorted = false;
 bool run = true;
 
 if(list[i].firstname > 1) {
  for (i = 0; i < (list[i].firstname-1); i++) {
  min = i;
  for (j = (i+1); j < list[i].firstname; j++) {
   if(list[j] < list[min]) min = j;
  }
 if (i != min) swap(list[i], list[min]);
 }
 sorted = true;
 }  
}

Comment: It keeps giving me operator errors. The other one keeps saying that vector<AddressBook> has no member named 'firstname', although it's named in the struct.

Comment: 66 23 C:\Users\Rebecca\Desktop\Ass2 ver25.cpp [Error] 'class std::vector<AddressBook>' has no member named 'firstname'

Comment: Again, code and its resulting errors belongs in your question, not walled into a comment. Is your main question how you can sort a vector of your structures based on a variety of criteria? Ie. Sort by first-name, or last-name, or last-name *then* first-name, etc? One way to do that is using custom comparators and [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: void sortFirstNames(vector<AddressBook>& list) {
 string firstname;
 char i;
 
 for (i = 0; i < list.firstname; i++) {
  sort(list.begin(), list.end());
 }
}

Comment: I want to be able to sort alphabetically by first name.

Comment: Sorry about the code. I'm new at this.

Comment: I suspected you were. Take a minute and read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are lots of questions that are likely already around that are closely related to your question as well, so taking the time to learn how to efficiently search on this site would be *very* beneficial as well.

Comment: I have searched through stack overflow over the last week, and I was able to answer a lot of my earlier questions, especially regarding reading and writing to file.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find what I was looking for regarding the sort, because most struct examples included class, which I don't need to use.